# How to solve logical formulas in haskell?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, gadt

I am working on a haskell program that includes these data type definitions as part of it:

```
data Term t (deriving Eq) where
Con     ::          a                               -> Term a
And     ::      Term Bool           -> Term Bool    -> Term Bool 
Or      ::      Term Bool           -> Term Bool    -> Term Bool 
Smaller ::      Term Int            -> Term Int     -> Term Bool
Plus    ::          Term Int        -> Term Int     -> Term Int
```

And data Formula ts where

```
data Formula ts where
Body   :: Term Bool                     -> Formula ()
Forall :: Show a 
     => [a] -> (Term a -> Formula as) -> Formula (a, as)
```

and also an eval function, which evaluates each Term t as:

```
eval :: Term t -> t
eval (Con i) =i
eval (And p q)=eval p && eval q
eval (Or p q)=eval p || eval q
eval(Smaller n m)=eval n < eval m
eval (Plus n m)    = eval n + eval m
```

And the following function that checks wether a Formula is satisfiable for any possible substitution of values:

```
satisfiable :: Formula ts -> Bool
satisfiable (Body( sth ))=eval sth
satisfiable (Forall xs f) = any (satisfiable . f . Con) xs
```

Now, i have been asked to write  a solution function that solves a given Formula :

```
solutions :: Formula ts -> [ts]
```

Also, i have the following Formulas as testing examples, that expects my solution to behave like this:

```
ex1 :: Formula ()
ex1 = Body (Con True)

ex2 :: Formula (Int, ())
ex2 = Forall [1..10] $ \n ->
    Body $ n `Smaller` (n `Plus` Con 1)

ex3 :: Formula (Bool, (Int, ()))
ex3 = Forall [False, True] $ \p -> 
  Forall [0..2] $ \n -> 
    Body $ p `Or` (Con 0 `Smaller` n)
```

the solution function should return:

```
*Solver>solutions ex1 
[()]

*Solver> solutions ex2
[(1,()),(2,()),(3,()),(4,()),(5,()),(6,()),(7,()),(8,()),(9,()),(10,())]

*Solver> solutions ex3
[(False,(1,())),(False,(2,())),(True,(0,())),(True,(1,())),(True,(2,()))]
```

My code for this function so far is:

```
solutions :: Formula ts -> [ts]
solutions(Body(sth))|satisfiable (Body( sth ))=[()]
        |otherwise=[]

solutions(Forall [a] f)|(satisfiable (Forall [a] f))=[(a,(helper $(f.Con) a) )]

|otherwise=[]
solutions(Forall (a:as) f)=solutions(Forall [a] f)++ solutions(Forall as f)
```

and the helper function is:

```
helper :: Formula ts -> ts
helper (Body(sth))|satisfiable (Body( sth ))=()
helper (Forall [a] f)|(satisfiable (Forall [a] f))=(a,((helper.f.Con) a) )
```

Finally, here is my question: with this solutions function, i can solve formulas which are either like ex1 and ex2 without any problems, but the problem is that i can not solve ex3 .meaning that my function does not work with formulas that include nested "Forall"s . any help with how can i do this, will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

`solutions` has to be recursive so that it can peel off arbitrary number of `Forall` layers:

```
solutions :: Formula ts -> [ts]
solutions (Body term) = [() | eval term]
solutions (Forall xs formula) = [ (x, ys) | x <- xs, ys <- solutions (formula (Con x)) ]
```

Examples:

```
λ» solutions ex1
[()]
λ» solutions ex2
[(1,()),(2,()),(3,()),(4,()),(5,()),(6,()),(7,()),(8,()),(9,()),(10,())]
λ» solutions ex3
[(False,(1,())),(False,(2,())),(True,(0,())),(True,(1,())),(True,(2,()))]
```

(as an aside, I think the `Forall` name is quite misleading and should be renamed to `Exists`, since your `satisfiable` function (and my `solutions` function, to keep in the spirit) accepts formulae where there's some choice of the variables to evaluate to `True`)